# How to implement foreach loop in addRoute syntax?

Tags: php

I am creating router from fast-route middleware.

```
// routes.php

return [
    ['GET', '/1', ['ShowMe','demo']],
    ['GET', '/2', ShowMe::class],
];
```

If I include this manually in simpleDispatcher's function everything works fine - **both routes are working**:

```
   // $r->addRoute('GET', '/ddd', ['ShowMe','demo']);
   // $r->addRoute('GET', '/ddd', ShowMe::class);
```

However, if I want to load routes from routes.php I am using such code:

```
foreach ($routes as $key => $route) {
   $r->addRoute($route[0], $route[1], [$route[2][0], $route[2][1]]);
  }
```

This work perfect for routes where functions are called like this: 
    ['GET', '/1', ['ShowMe','demo']],

**So I modify (because I have 2 route types and want this syntax support both of them):**

```
   $r->addRoute($route[0], $route[1], [implode(",", $route[2])]);
```

And it doesn't work now in both route's types:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ...\index.php on line 69

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Invalid request handler: array
```

Comment: is this `'GET', '/1', ['ShowMe,demo']` supposed to be a correct syntax ? Why are you imploding ?

Comment: @Cid Yes, this syntax is correct. However there are 2 types of routes:
'GET', '/1', ['ShowMe,demo'] and 'GET', '/2', ShowMe::class - that's why I implode.

Comment: Do note this will not give you the expected result, as implode returns a string, your last array will only contain one element - [demo](https://ideone.com/DFBKyL)

Comment: What is the syntax to add routes with class name ?

Comment: @Cid , I have checked once again the issue. And it was Class issue with your $route[2]. So this way it works perfect! Thank you for your support!

Comment: @Cid As AmalK answer was a first one, I have marked his answer as correct. But I appreciate your support too! Good luck in all of your projects. Thank you for have helped me to resolve an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your `foreach` loop syntax
The syntax is `foreach($arrayName as $key => $value)`

```
foreach ($routes as $key => $route) {
   $r->addRoute($routes[$key]); # or  simply  $r->addRoute($route);
  }
```

Secondly, the `implode()` function returns the array as a string which I guess you don't want.
So simply say:

```
$r->addRoute($route[0], $route[1], $route[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Your syntax is work for first route type, however for a second one there is an error: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Invalid request handler: object

Comment: I have checked once again. And it was Class issue. So your syntax work perfect. Thank you for your support.